# Is there a way to make the mapping dynamic loop between the XML scheme?

Tags: bloomberg, fix-protocol

Setuing a fix engine for Bloomberg FXGO for FX Derivatives.
Although using an XML scheme (DataDictionary=FIX_BBG.xml) for the mapping of the FIX message, I receive an error of

```
*FIX Message": "8=FIX.4.4|9=156|35=3|34=1770|49=MAP|52=20220118-14:39:48.607|56=MAP_BBG_BETA|145=FX|45=1783|**58=Out of order repeating group members, field=602|371=602|372=8|373=15|10=180"***
```

This due to the fact that the tags sequence is repeating across different type of transactions;
For the above tag 602 is coming in normal sequence and then repeats itself after tag 675.

Is there a way to make the mapping dynamic loop between the XML scheme?

Tried to add the tag 602 in multiple location in XML scheme or changing the order but still receiving the same error

Adding a sample FIX msg, 602 tag to 1074 in the sequence is repeating twice, whereas in the XML schema is once and in arithmetic order from 1 to 20,XXX tag. and this is resulting to rejection.

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=2317|35=8|49=MAP_BLP_BETA|56=MAP_BETA|34=1933|144=FX|52=20220708-15:01:49|30=XOFF|60=20220708-14:55:49.210|120=USD|150=F|31=1.203294|151=0|32=240003|64=20220719|6=1.203294|1056=288794.17|37=3-2-XXXXXXXXXXX-0-0|1057=Y|38=240003|218=0|39=2|40=G|460=4|1300=XOFF|1390=0|11=3-2-XXXXXXXXXXX-0-0|14=240003|194=1.2032|854=0|15=GBP|75=20220708|195=0.000593|17=3-2-XXXXXXXXXXX-0-0|167=FXSWAP|797=Y|22277=0|48=TGBYHN1234|528=P|22280=2|22=4|54=B|55=GBP/USD|119=288794.17|2489=FX_CASH_RFQ_815676229|78=2|79=TESTVENUE|80=240003|79=TESTVENUE|80=240003|555=2|**600=GBP/USD|****1788=1|602=TGBYHN1234|603=4****|607=4|609=FXFWD|624=1|556=GBP|687=240003|654=1|587=6|588=20220719|675=USD|637=1.203294|1073=0.000094|1074=288794.17|****600=GBP/USD|1788=2|602=EZBCKS7MP4D1|603=4|607=4|609=FXFWD|624=2|556=GBP|687=240003|654=2|587=6|588=20220812|675=USD|637=1.203887|1073=0.000687|1074=288936.49|**10009=6|10010=VENUE1|10011=1.203334|22161=1.203927|22162=0.000593|22163=0.000687|22485=1.20324|22486=0|22545=0|10010=VENUE2|10011=1.203304|22161=1.203897|22162=0.000593|22163=0.000687|22485=1.20321|22486=0|22545=0|10010=VENUE3|10011=1.203324|22161=1.203917|22162=0.000593|22163=0.000687|22485=1.20323|22486=0|22545=0|10010=VENUE5|10011=0|22161=0|22162=0|22163=0|22485=0|22486=0|22545=0|10010=MidRate|10011=1.20324|22161=1.203845|22162=0.000605|22163=0.000695|22485=1.2032|22486=0|22545=0|10010=RefRate|10011=1.203294|22161=1.203887|22162=0.000593|22163=0.000687|22485=1.2032|22486=0|22545=0|22078=1|22079=1.203294|22080=20|22081=12|453=7|448=XOFF|447=G|452=64|802=1|523=TESTUIT12345678|803=4025|448=BGTB|447=D|452=13|802=5|523=Pricer Test USER4|803=1|523=24876081|803=2|523=USER1|803=9|523=12345QAZWSX|803=4025|523=Y|803=4047|448=125698745|447=P|452=12|2376=24|802=1|523=Y|803=4047|448=125698745|447=P|452=122|2376=24|802=1|523=Y|803=4047|448=VENUE2|447=D|452=1|802=5|523=Pricer BGAU|803=1|523=27391323|803=2|523=TESTUSER|803=9|523=12345QAZWSX|803=4025|523=Y|803=4046|448=PRODUCT TYPE|447=D|452=16|802=1|523=Dealing (RFQ)|803=4|448=24876081|447=D|452=11|1907=2|1903=TESTUTI2333333|1905=1234QWERT|1904=0|1906=5|2411=1|1903=TESTID12345667789|1905=1234QWERT|1904=0|1906=5|2411=2|768=2|769=20220708-14:55:49.210|770=1|769=20220708-14:55:40.000|770=10|2668=2|2669=0|2670=4|2669=1|2670=7|10=243|
```

Comment: Don't know if this helps you further but the tags in the repeating group need to be in exactly the same order as in the data dictionary. Maybe you can show the message that you send along with the specific extract from the dictionary.

Comment: Added above a sample msg, however we are looking to have a dynamic loop over the XML in fix engine to avoid going to do 1-1 mapping msg by msg

Comment: Which FIX engine do you use?

Comment: And i still don't know what you mean by "having a dynamic loop over the XML"